# Does the electrical parameters of a packaged transistor change from bare die transistors?

Tags: mosfet, packages, parasitic-capacitance, die

When comparing the electrical parameters of the MOSFET/Transistors, do they change when the package type changes? Are the parasitic parameters of the packaged MOSFET and bare die MOSFET change.

It is know that the thermal parameters do change but does it have an influence on the electrical characteristics?

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific.  If you're talking about an RF device, the answer is yes, the package can influence some parameters.  In the case of a big power MOSFET, the answer is no, as most/all electrical parameters are set by the die.

Comment: Have you ever seen a MOSFET device that has different electrical parameters specified based on package type?

Comment: Not really, but the thermal parameters do changebased on the package. I am not sure if they influence the electrical parameters too.

Comment: I think a package could add very slightly to parasitic capacitance and leakage, but this wouldn't change much from package to package as the material is well-defined.  Meaning, do not use a plastic part in place of a ceramic one, etc.

Comment: I found this: https://irf.com/technical-info/whitepaper/pcimeur03packageparasitics.pdf

Comment: "Big power MOSFETs" are no exception either: I've seen IGBT/MOSFET modules with so much stray inductance they'll practically blow themselves up doing anything, and one wonders why (or how) they exist as a product at all...

Comment: But a MOSFET module (which I have not come across) is not the same thing as a single MOSFET in a package, is it?

Comment: @DKNguyen - Thanks for the paper.  We've used the Direct FETs (DFETs) in some critical high current applications.  But their main advantage there was the low ON+Pkg+Mounting resistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two sides to this: direct effects from the physical nature of the package, and secondary effects due to thermal variations.

The primary difference from the physical side is the parasitic inductance of the leads. This is a common theme with all packaging - the bigger the part, the more parasitic inductance you have. This is particularly important for things like high speed switching and linear operation under a control loop, primarily in relation to the inductance of the gate pin.

The longer bond wires and leads will also introduce a very small amount of additional resistance. This is typically very small at DC, and in high current MOSFETs it'll be offset by the use of packages with multiple pins for the source and drain. The \$R_G\$ is typically a little lower in smaller package MOSFETs, which again can be useful for fast switching. At higher frequencies you'll start to see things like skin effects, which will increase the characteristic impedance of the lines, and these effects will generally be of lower magnitude with bare die packages.

There will also be a tiny increase in parasitic capacitance from the leads. However, this change is smaller than the typical variance in gate capacitance, so it can be ignored in almost all circumstances (unless we're talking RF or extremely fast switching).

Combined together, these effects lead to noticeably lower impedance in switching or RF operation. In slow or DC operation the smaller parasitics *from physical differences* are not that noticeable.

The thermal effects are where things get far more interesting. With a bare die package you have no \$R_{th(J-C)}\$ and \$R_{th(C-A)}\$, because there is no case - you just have \$R_{th(J-A)}\$. This also removes the heat capacity inherent to the package's thermal interface. This means that the thermal impedance between the junction and the air/board can be extremely low. Almost all properties of a MOSFET will vary over temperature - the \$V_{gs}\$ vs \$I_{ds}\$ curve will change shape, the FBSOA varies significantly, the \$C_{gs}\$, \$C_{gd}\$, and \$C_{ds}\$ will vary, the threshold / Miller plateau voltage will change. All of these parameters interact in complex manners, and their thermal coefficients depend on the type of MOSFET (planar vs. trench, Si vs. SiC, etc.) both in magnitude and direction (PTC/NTC).

Something else to consider here is that you can't just evaluate these effects as if the system was in thermal equilibrium. Aside from \$R_{ds(on)}\$, the parasitic properties of the MOSFET are largely relevant during transients, i.e. in dynamic operation. The thermal impedance between the MOSFET die and the environment means that a transient increase in power dissipation within the die can cause a transient spike in junction temperature, far above the case temperature. The thermal coefficients of the MOSFET's parameters are based on the junction temperature, not the case temperature, so the dynamic performance of a MOSFET can be quite heavily affected by the thermal impedance of its package. Removing the package and going to bare die helps reduce the thermal impedance, meaning that the temperature variance of the junction is smaller, i.e. \$\Delta T_j\$ can be made smaller for a given \$\Delta P_D\$ during transients.

Answer (score 4):

> When comparing the electrical parameters of the MOSFET/Transistors, do they change when the package type changes? Are the parasitic parameters of the packaged MOSFET and bare die MOSFET change.

Yes.

The question you have to ask is 'is the change significant?'

The main difference between packaged and bare die is bond wire and lead frame inductance, of typically 1 nH per mm of path length, though of course there are small resistive and capacitive changes as well.

At microwave frequencies, this changes the performance of transistors radically.

At Switch Mode Power Supply frequencies, a few nH makes absolutely no difference at all.